# obtaining column value from GridView selected row in Devexpress

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I'm in DevExpress trying to do something rather simple.  Get the value of a column in a DevExpress Gridview for a particular row a user selected.  Should be simple but having no success.  I can get the  correct overall row count for the grid via -

```
grdA.VisibleRowCount;
```

But cannot seem to get what I am after - a particular column value for a selected row.  Tried everything including:

```
grdA.GetSelectedFieldValues("ClientID");
```

no avail, returns zero count.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this using the WinForms GridControl or ASPxGridView?

Comment: it is using aspxGridView

Answer (score 0):

the function GetSelectedFieldValues does a callback function,
in this case I think, you need to do another function that actually receives the values for example:

```
function rowClick(s, e) {
    s.GetSelectedFieldValues('ClientID', getValues);   
 }

function getValues(values) {
    alert(values);
}
```